# EF Core 5 how do you hard cast a property inside an .Include now?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Before upgrading to EF Core 5, we could cast `c.Progresses` like shown below. Does someone know how I use this correctly now?

```
var case = caseRepository
    .Many(c => c.Id == caseId)
    .Include(c => c.Progresses as Progress) // this breaks
        .ThenInclude(p => ProgressType)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The expression 'Convert(c.Progresses, Progress)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

**Edit**: this fixed it:

```
var case = caseRepository
    .Many(c => c.Id == caseId)
    .Include(c => c.Progresses)
        .ThenInclude(p => (p as Progress).ProgressType)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Why is this change needed after upgrading to EF Core 5?

Comment: Probably because they changed the mechanism to enable filtered `Include`. It's irony that now you can no longer "filter" scalar navigation properties, apparently.

Comment: Upgrading from what? EF6 or EF Core 1/2/3.x? The cast inside `Include` seems useless anyway, why don't you simply remove it? And what exactly are you trying to achieve with it?  If you need to include derived entity related data, use cast inside `ThenInclude` as shown in the docs. As of *why* (in case you are upgrading from earlier  EF Core version), I'm afraid you have to ask the EF Core designers in their GitHub issue tracker. Sometimes they fix logical bugs in previous implementations.